# DataSourceInitializer does not get called

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.1

I am setting up java config for database in my spring mvc app, and what I cannot figure out is why DataSourceInitializer bean does not get created, i.e.  `dataSourceInitializer` method is never called.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {CustomerRepository.class})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Resource
    Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.pwd"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource) {
        final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
        return initializer;
    }

    @Bean
    public DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("classpath:/db/sql/create-db.sql", DatabaseConfig.class));
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("classpath:/db/sql/insert-data.sql", DatabaseConfig.class));
        return databasePopulator;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setPersistenceUnitName("CustomersPU");
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.myapp.domain");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);

        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());

        return factory;
    }

    Properties jpaProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        ...
        return props;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Exception that I get is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/myapp/conf/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: CustomersPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at ....
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: CustomersPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:877)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:805)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [CUSTOMERS]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
    ... 62 more
```

What I am looking for is to have it configured similar to this configuration: embedded database + special username and password + paths to schema and insertion sql files. Like described here https://github.com/JohnathanMarkSmith/HelloSpringJavaBasedJavaConfig

**UPDATE**
If I just use EmbeddableDatabase, then it does not allow me to define username, password and DB connection URL, which is necessary to me. The following example works, but it does not allow me to define username, password and DB connection URL.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScript("classpath:/db/sql/create-db.sql")
            .addScript("classpath:/db/sql/insert-data.sql")
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Can you post an exception stacktrace?

Comment: Yes, added stack trace

Comment: Hmm, this stacktrace doesn't relate to `dataSourceInitializer`. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: nikpon, I added the desired behavior, however I thought it was clear already from the beginning: I want to have dataSourceInitializer bean to be called from my java config.

Comment: yes it's clear [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), instead of solving problem X you have to solve problem Y, then asking why problem X is not solved.

Comment: Good to know. After I updated my question, is my question more straightforward now?